# Laravel and Brew installation with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5, homebrew

I have just moved from linux to mac and am having some issues installing PHP with the right drivers for Laravel.

I ran `brew install homebrew/php/php56-mysqlnd_ms`

but now I keep getting this error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php56-mcrypt/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-mcrypt/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php56-mcrypt/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56-mcrypt/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()

PHP Version => 5.6.21
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error? I am at a loss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing mcrypt . You can try ,

`brew install php54-mcrypt --without-homebrew-php`

And then , in `/etc/php.ini` add,

`extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.24/mcrypt.so"`

I hope this will help , please let us know

Comment: I get this error when running the brew install Error: Formulae found in multiple taps: * homebrew/php/php53 * josegonzalez/php/php53

Comment: try `brew untap josegonzalez/homebrew-php` and then run previous command again .

Comment: @DevinGray let us know.

Comment: good news is that the error is gone :P bad news is that this is now a thing Fatal error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset()

Comment: Can you upgrade or reinstall the php again , this is the easiest way I can think of now ... @DevinGray

Comment: Or if in this manual process you are having problems then please take a look into answer by @Sergi .. Down below. This is also an easy process to do that

Comment: @DevinGray if you only need a local server for development purpose and it is in hurry , then try ` MAMP `  , Here is a link of a blog post on medium which will take you through the whole process , https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/install-laravel-5-on-os-x-23f3578386f1#.9x8vl64qr

Comment: I just got it up and running on a mamp server for now. I am looking into installing homestead which will be a big task as I have never used a VM before. So will have to see how that goes. But the mamp option worked, it just feels dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have to install the module mcrypt of php.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
sudo composer update
```

Other thing that if you want to use mac and linux you can use Vagrant, is really nice how it works with virtualbox + vagrant you can have stack on other OS.

https://www.vagrantup.com/

And this is a nice project with vagrant for install all the the technologies you need.

https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash

Comment: Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
 * homebrew/php/php53
 * josegonzalez/php/php53

Comment: I get the above error on brew install. I am also looking into homestead and vagrant, but I need to get a local site up quickly haha